# count selected rows DB2

Tags: sql, function, db2

I´m trying to count the all the rows. but I dont get any good reslut, any tips?

The best would be if I could do this with a sub-query.

> ```
>  select distinct  FIPBNR, FILAR1, filev1,fiben1,fiart,fiben2,fiurk,
>  count(*)
>
>
>  from TRUFPR424/TRAFI00 
>  where fifili <> 0 and filev1 = '6253744' and fiurk != 'U'
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "group by because I get to many count answers."? Please add sample data and what you should get as result on that data

Comment: I will reformulate the question, I want to count all rows.

thx for taking your time.

Comment: Tough day at the office???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a select in parens and treat it like a table.

```
select count(*) from ( 
select distinct  FIPBNR, FILAR1, filev1,fiben1,fiart,fiben2,fiurk


 from TRUFPR424/TRAFI00 
 where fifili <> 0 and filev1 = '6253744' and fiurk != 'U'

) as a
```

Comment: != might not work depends on actual database...   <> is not equal for a database

Comment: Thank you, this counted the rows, but why did´t it show are row values? I´m new to SQL and sub-queries is a burden!

Comment: It was sql to count all the distinct rows.  If you need  counts of the groupings then that is a group by statement.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear.

Are you trying to count the total number of unique combinations based on your query?

Try:

```
 select count(distinct  FIPBNR, FILAR1, filev1,fiben1,fiart,fiben2,fiurk)
 from TRUFPR424/TRAFI00 
 where fifili <> 0 and filev1 = '6253744' and fiurk != 'U'
```

Comment: I will reformulate the question, I want to count all rows.

thx for taking your time.

Comment: @The.B . . . This does return the number of rows that your query would return.

Comment: is there any other ways? remeber this is DB2. it gives me an error message that say " count not vaild"